# Problems with JOGL and Swing

Tags: java, swing, opengl, jogl

I'm using JOGL and have a glcanvas I'm rendering to. However, all it does is flash red and then turn black. I tried using different sample code and it does the same.
This is my display function, let me know if there is anything wrong please!

```
public static void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable)
{
     System.out.println("Runnning display");
     GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();



     // Clear screen
     gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 1, 0.5f);  // Purple
     gl.glClear(GL2.GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT | GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL2.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

     int [] vbo_handles = new int[2];
     gl.glGenBuffers(2, vbo_handles, 0);


     gl.glEnableClientState(GL2.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

     float[] vertices = {  0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, //Top
               -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, //Bottom Left
                1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f  //Bottom Right
                                };


     FloatBuffer fbVertices = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(vertices);
     gl.glBindBuffer(GL2.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_handles[VERTICES_IDX]);
     int numBytes = vertices.length*4;
     gl.glBufferData(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, numBytes, fbVertices, GL.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

     // Associate Vertex attribute 0 with the last bound VBO
     gl.glVertexAttribPointer(0 /* the vertex attribute */, 3,
          GL2.GL_FLOAT, false /* normalized? */, 0 /* stride */,
                                 0 /* The bound VBO data offset */);

     // VBO
     gl.glBindBuffer(GL2.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); // You can unbind the VBO after it have been associated using glVertexAttribPointer

     gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);


     float[] colors = {    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, //Top color (red)
         0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, //Bottom Left color (black)
         1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.9f  //Bottom Right color (yellow) with 10% transparence
         };

    FloatBuffer fbColors = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(colors);

    // Select the VBO, GPU memory data, to use for colors
    gl.glBindBuffer(GL2.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboHandles[COLOR_IDX]);

    numBytes = colors.length * 4;
    gl.glBufferData(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, numBytes, fbColors, GL.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    fbColors = null; // It is OK to release CPU color memory after transfer to GPU

     //Associate Vertex attribute 1 with the last bound VBO
    gl.glVertexAttribPointer(1 /* the vertex attribute */, 4 /* four possitions used for each vertex */,
    GL2.GL_FLOAT, false /* normalized? */, 0 /* stride */,
            0 /* The bound VBO data offset */);

    gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    gl.glDrawArrays(GL2.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3); //Draw the vertices as triangle

    gl.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0); // Allow release of vertex position memory

   }
}
```

```
It seems like it isn't calling the display function for the GLEventListener.


public class UserInterface implements GLEventListener{
    private JTree tree;
    JPopupMenu popupmenu;
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("NecroTEK 3D Game Graphics Engine");

    public void initUI()
    {
        System.out.println("Initializing UI");
        TreeDemo();

        //JFrame frame = new JFrame("NecroTek 3D Game Modeling Engine");
        JPopupMenu popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();
        popupMenu.setSize(200, 400);
        popupMenu.setBackground(Color.black);
        popupMenu.setForeground(Color.white);
        popupMenu.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.white));



        /**********MENUBAR - TOP MENU***************/

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        menuBar.setLayout(new BoxLayout(menuBar, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));



        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        fileMenu.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 10));


        fileMenu.setToolTipText("Load and Save Projects and Scenes");

        JMenu EditMenu = new JMenu("Edit");
        EditMenu.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 10));
        EditMenu.setToolTipText("Cut, Copy and Paste");

        JMenu ViewMenu = new JMenu("View");
        ViewMenu.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 10));
        JMenuItem clear = new JMenuItem("Clear");
        clear.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 10));
        JMenuItem fullscreen = new JMenuItem("Fullscreen");
        fullscreen.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 10));
        JMenu imagemode = new JMenu("Image Mode");
        imagemode.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 10));
        JMenuItem bitmap = new JMenuItem("Bitmap");
        bitmap.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 10));
        JMenuItem greyscale = new JMenuItem("Greyscale");
        greyscale.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 10));
        JMenuItem rgbcolor = new JMenuItem("RGB Color");
        rgbcolor.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 10));
        JMenuItem cmykcolor = new JMenuItem("CMYK Color");
        cmykcolor.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 10));
        JMenuItem eightbitchannel = new JMenuItem("8 bit channel");
        eightbitchannel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 10));
        JMenuItem sixteenbitchannel = new JMenuItem("16 bit channel");
        sixteenbitchannel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 10));
        JMenuItem thirtytwobitchannel = new JMenuItem("32 bit channel");
        thirtytwobitchannel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 10));
        imagemode.add(bitmap);
        imagemode.add(greyscale);
        imagemode.add(rgbcolor);
        imagemode.add(cmykcolor);
        imagemode.add(eightbitchannel);
        imagemode.add(sixteenbitchannel);
        imagemode.add(thirtytwobitchannel);
        ViewMenu.add(imagemode);

        JMenu shadingMenu = new JMenu("Shading");
        shadingMenu.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 10));
        JMenuItem smooth = new JMenuItem("Smooth");
        smooth.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 10));
        JMenuItem flat = new JMenuItem("Flat");
        flat.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 10));
        shadingMenu.add(smooth );
        smooth.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 10));
        shadingMenu.add(flat );
        ViewMenu.add(shadingMenu);

        JMenuItem renderpresets = new JMenuItem("Render Presets");
        renderpresets.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 10));
        ViewMenu.add(renderpresets);

        JMenu performance = new JMenu("Performance");
        performance.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 10));

        JMenu mathperformance = new JMenu("Math");
        mathperformance.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 10));

So that's a stub of the UI function. The end of it is..

        /**********************/

        frame.setBounds(0, 0, 640, 480);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1200,800));
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible( true );



        mainScreen.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        left.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        right.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        bottom.setLayout(new FlowLayout());


        /*
        GLProfile glprofile = GLProfile.getDefault();
        GLCapabilities glcapabilities = new GLCapabilities( glprofile );
        final ` glcanvas = new GLCanvas( glcapabilities );
         glcanvas.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100,100));
         glcanvas.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100,100));
        int z = 300;
        int h = 300;

        JPanel canvasPanel = new JPanel();
        canvasPanel.add(glcanvas);
        frame.getContentPane().add(glcanvas);
        frame.setSize(frame.getContentPane().getPreferredSize());
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setName("3D Line");

         frame.setTitle("Necro3D World Editor");
         frame.pack();
         frame.setVisible(true);        


        */











frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setName("3D Line");

 frame.setTitle("Necro3D World Editor");
 frame.pack();
 frame.setVisible(true);


//addWindowListener(this);

JPanel toolPanel = new JPanel();
toolPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
toolPanel.add(toolbar);


JPanel rightsidePanel = new JPanel();
rightsidePanel.add(right);
rightsidePanel.add(toolPanel);


frame.add(mainScreen, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.add(left, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
frame.add(rightsidePanel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
frame.add(bottom, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
frame.setBackground(Color.RED);
```

/*************OPENGL STUFF******************/

```
GLProfile glprofile = GLProfile.getDefault();
GLCapabilities glcapabilities = new GLCapabilities( glprofile );
final GLCanvas glcanvas = new GLCanvas( glcapabilities );

glcanvas.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100,100));
 glcanvas.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100,100));
 glcanvas.setBounds(0,0, 520, 320);
int z = 300;
int h = 300;

JPanel canvasPanel = new JPanel();
canvasPanel.add(glcanvas);
mainScreen.add(canvasPanel);

/*****************************************/




    /**************DIALOGUES*************/

    layersButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            JPanel testPanel = new JPanel();
            testPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(20,20));

            JLabel title = new JLabel("Select layer");
            testPanel.add(title);
            for (int i=0;i<40;i++)
            {
                JButton newbutton = new JButton(" ");
                newbutton.setSize(new Dimension(10,10));
                newbutton.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
                testPanel.add(newbutton);
            }
```

...

```
frame.add(mainScreen, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    //frame.add(canvasPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.add(left, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
    frame.add(rightsidePanel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
    frame.add(bottom, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    frame.setBackground(Color.RED);



    frame.setSize(500, 300);
    //center the JFrame on the screen
    //centerWindow(frame);

    //
    //4. Size the frame.

    frame.pack();

    //5. Show it.
    frame.setVisible(true);
    glcanvas.requestFocus();
    System.out.println("Frame Set Visible")


            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, testPanel);

        }

    });
```

....

```
@Override
    public void display(GLAutoDrawable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Display");
        GLRenderer.display(arg0);

    }
    @Override
    public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Dispose");
    }
    @Override
    public void init(GLAutoDrawable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Init");
        GLRenderer.init(arg0);
    }
    @Override
    public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Reshape");
    }


    /**************/
    // An inner class to check whether mouse events are the popup trigger
    class MousePopupListener extends MouseAdapter {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            checkPopup(e);
        }

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            checkPopup(e);
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            checkPopup(e);
        }

        private void checkPopup(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
                popupmenu.show(popupmenu, e.getX(), e.getY());
            }
        }
    }


    // An inner class to show when popup events occur
    class PopupPrintListener implements PopupMenuListener {
        public void popupMenuWillBecomeVisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Popup menu will be visible!");
        }

        public void popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Popup menu will be invisible!");
        }

        public void popupMenuCanceled(PopupMenuEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Popup menu is hidden!");
        }`
    }
```

}

None of the GL listener stuff is executing.

Comment: Use gDEBugger to find out why it turns black. That way you may rule out accidental clear, missing buffer swap, broken buffers, transforms, opengl errors, and analyze any other states that may interfere with your rendering in real time.

Comment: Can't. I'm running on a mac and gDEBugger only supports windows and linux

Comment: Please provide a SSCCE: sscce.org Your source code is incomplete. I advise you to test a more simple example as a first step in order to find more easily what is wrong. Moreover, you don't provide enough information about your computer to help us to find the culprit, you don't mention your OS version, your JRE, your graphics card, the version number of your driver, ...

Comment: Ok. In the end of the function does glGetErrors return anything but no error?

Comment: The issue seems to be that the event listener's functions that are implemented aren't being called/ See my edit above.

Comment: glErrors reports nothing. I am using Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.3. My JRE is      java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode) I'm using JOGL version 4, and gfx card Intel Iris 1536 MB. CPU: intel 2.6 ghz intel core i5, 8 GB DDR memory  anything else?

Comment: There is no "JOGL version 4". The latest version is JOGL 2.3.2. Please indicate which JOGL version you use.

Comment: I see no animator in your source code, you should have looked at the more simple examples I mentioned on wikipedia, especially mine: https://gist.github.com/gouessej/3420e2b6f632efdddf98#file-joglquad-java-L74

Answer (score 1):

Several things seem to be wrong:

- you are generating new buffers each `display()` with `glGenBuffers`
- `glEnableClientState` is deprecated
- you are loading each `display()` the `vertices` data into `vbo_handles[VERTICES_IDX]` with `glBufferData`. If `vertices` are static, you don't need that
- same for `vboHandles[COLOR_IDX]`
- since `fbColors` is direct buffer, you can't clean it with by assigning it to `null`, you have to do something like [this](https://github.com/elect86/jogl-samples/blob/master/jogl-samples/src/framework/BufferUtils.java#L279)